# Revision history for Japanese

Tags: bug, feature-request, status-completed

Revisions for Japanese text are difficult to read as often an entire `<p>`aragraph is marked as having been changed.

In [this post](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/posts/17939/revisions) a **single** character was changed (revision 2). However, the `inline`, `side-by-side` and `side-by-side markdown` diffs look as follows.

[image]
[image]
[image]

It would be better if a "word boundary" is at least detected as a change of script (hiragana vs. katakana vs. kanji).

Comment: Oh thanks I find another error looking at the image :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I apologize for having missed this before. We actually [added](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1605/%E7%B7%A8%E9%9B%86%E3%81%AE%E5%B7%AE%E5%88%86%E8%A1%A8%E7%A4%BA%E3%81%8C%E5%88%86%E3%81%8B%E3%82%8A%E3%81%AB%E3%81%8F%E3%81%84/1606#1606) the possibility to enable a heuristic for Japanese compound segmentation in the diff engine, it was just never enabled on this site. I have enabled it now. Your example now looks like this:

[image: screenshot of the improved diff]

I *think* the fact that (unlike on Japanese Stack Overflow) this site contains a mixture of English and Japanese shouldn't be a problem, but we should keep an eye on that to be sure.

Comment: Fantastic, thank you! Oh... this is so much nicer.

Answer (score 1):

I know the Unicode Consortium has already defined [how to mechanically decide word boundaries](http://unicode.org/reports/tr29/#Word_Boundaries). The algorithm is comparatively simple if Unicode properties are available, and sufficient to fulfill this site's need, at least.

Side effects unassessed.

Comment: If decent word boundaries were implemented, revisions on http://jp.stackoverflow.com would benefit as well, I think.

Comment: @Earthliŋ 確かに…！

Comment: @Earthliŋ Oh, by "side effects" I mean lest it break some other foreign languages. But well, active SE sites that require non-alphabet are only Japanese, Chinese and Hebrew (mathese excluded), so far so good...

Comment: Oh, there's Arabic...

Comment: Arabic? I don't there is an active site in Arabic... I guess Arabic is used on Islam.SE and Hebrew on Mi Yodeya.

Comment: Yes that was what I tried to say. Sorry for confusion :)

Comment: @Earthliŋ I also found Hinduism SE with much Devanagari, but thankfully they use spaces.